# Xcode - Can I develop for iOS 11.1 in El Capitan?

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode, ios

I'm a software development student and I'm building an iOS app for a class.

The thing is I have a `MacBook Pro Mid 2009` with `El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G17023)`
and an `iPhone 5s` running `iOS 11.1.2 (15B202)`.

The latest version of Xcode compatible with El Capitan (I think) is `8.2.1` and it is not compatible with my iOS version.

The app I'm trying to make does not require ARKit or anything that advanced and I would like to know if is there a way I can make this work with my actual devices?

I really don't have the money to upgrade my MacBook for a newer one nor for an older iPhone.

Thanks a lot for your help!

---

**Edit**: I no longer have this problem but obviously the question will stay open because we haven't found a solution nor a proper answer.
What I did was install [This High Sierra Patcher](http://dosdude1.com/highsierra/) and from there update Xcode and everything necessary to develop.

I do not recommend this: you are making modifications to your computer that can result in unexpected behavior and you know, all that anti-piracy speech... and also Xcode runs terribly slow (there is a reason why this computer model cannot be updated anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you get a better answer, because this is not ideal but is all I have:

You *could* develop using the latest version of Xcode that will run on your Mac using the simulator for day-to-day testing. Then when you really need to test on a real device, upload a beta to the App Store, configure yourself as an Internal Tester and use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) to download the app to your 'phone.

Edit: This may also require a full developer account!